# Getting checkbox id out of local storage for with JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, local-storage

I am working on a form that on reload has to save and show the marked checkboxes,
i made the code that can save it in to local storage but now i don't know how to get the id's of the checkboxes out of the local storage so they will be checkt again on reloading the page.

Here is a  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpn05aky/)

The code:

```js
// this code saves the marked checkbox in the local storage

$('.required-option').on('click', function() {
  var fav, favs = [];
  $('.required-option').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
    fav = {
      id: $(this).attr('id'),
      value: $(this).prop('checked')
    };
    if (fav.value === true) {
      favs.push(fav.id);
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("checkbox", JSON.stringify(favs));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like8" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like9" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store only the ID's of checked checkboxes, Here in example I have stored `#` prefixed concatenated selector string.

```
var elems = $('.required-option');
elems.on('click', function() {
    //Iterate checked checkboxes and store selector like #xxx
    var checkedCheckboxes = elems.filter(':checked').map(function() {
        return '#' + this.id;
    }).get().join(',');
    localStorage.setItem("checkedCheckboxes", checkedCheckboxes);
});

var checkedCheckboxesselector = localStorage.getItem("checkedCheckboxes");
if (!!checkedCheckboxesselector) {
    $(checkedCheckboxesselector).prop('checked', true);
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/owgd5v78/)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of achieving this is to just store the `id` attributes of the checked boxes. Storing unselected items is a little redundant. Try this:

```js
$('.required-option').on('click', function() {
    var favs = $('.required-option:checked').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    localStorage.setItem("checkbox", JSON.stringify(favs));
})

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkbox") || '[]').forEach(function(id) {
    $('#' + id).prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like8" />
<input type="checkbox" class="required-option" id="like9" />
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jpn05aky/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage.getItem()` to get the items and `JSON.parse()` to parse the string to js object(array in our case) on document ready of your page

```
$.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkbox")),function(i,v){
$('#'+v).attr('checked','checked'); //or as stated in the comments .prop('checked', true)
});
```

Comment: It's better `.prop('checked', true)`  becaue `attr()` doesn't works fine with checkboxes or radiobuttons

Comment: ca you provide documentation of your claim  @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Read here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName
**As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.**

Comment: It's a wide and old topic. If you want to manage properties dinamically on DOM tree, you must use `prop()` and not `attr()`. In fact, you can find tons of questions on stackoverflow that OP uses `attr()` and doesn't work for checkboxes or radiobuttons, and the solution was change to `prop()`. There are tons of documentation, so search on google, it's not difficult to find it.

Comment: Here you are the best explained article about that:  http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/metodo-prop-attr.html . It's in spanish language but you can translate it with google.

Comment: from " the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. " in my opinion in this case is valid to use `attr()`

Comment: If you try it, it doesn't work, at least with jQuery 2.x. Remember that versions 1.x are too old right now. The default value must be setted on the HTML, and the management of that property must be with javascript, not HTML, it's because `attr()` doesn't works and `prop()` works